# Is there a way to disable onDelete animation on SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I wanted to show an actionsheet to confirm deletion of a row in a list.  When swiping to delete or tapped on delete, the 'Delete' animation is always activated even when I've not deleted the row.

The deletion is performed only after user confirm on Actionsheet in my case.  Thus, the 'Delete' animation is confusing and unpleasant to the user.

Is there a way to disable the 'Delete' animation where the row disappeared and then appear again in my case since the deletion of the row is not performed in '.onDelete()'?

Comment: Would you demo somehow what do you mean?

Comment: I'm interested on this. Have you got a soultion?